# Button to dissapear after been colapssed?

Tags: css, wordpress, button, woocommerce

Hi i have one small issue. I have used Wordpress plugin to insert Contact Form 7 form into collapsed button, that is loading CF7 form when is pressed. Now i want that button to disapear after been collapsed. I checked and found this CSS class that is loaded when button is collapsed, and added just display:none but seems that is not working.

```
button#bg-showmore-action-5aa011ecd8ad50026368201.bg-showmore-plg-button bg-
orange-button bg-close {
display:none;
}
```

and this is entire HTML from that button:

```
<button id="bg-showmore-action-5aa0192e2a29b3050071453" class="bg-showmore-
plg-button bg-orange-button bg-close" style=" 
color:#4a4949;">Enquire</button>
```

[Link](http://www.marlonadekoya.com/product/ingrained-in-the-motherland/) from page where yellow button is present. How to hide button after been collapsed?

This is image before colapsed:

[image]

and this is image after been pressed the button:

[image]

yellow button is stick at bottom on end of form. I want to disapear after form been collapsed. I used this plugin to generate that button:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-hidecollapse-expand/
```

Comment: may be someother css is overwriting your changes , use display:none !important

Comment: Can you also provide the entire code relating to your issue? We can't help debug if we only have the css.

Comment: @Naga Sai  added also !important, but nothing changed.

Comment: provide screenshot or html code related this issue , so that it will be easy to debug

Comment: Provided images in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css code, notice the `.` (for classes) and `#` (for IDs) is not present in the code for some of the items. Try something like this:

Ok, saw your update... so to be more specific, try:

```
.bg-showmore-plg-button.bg-orange-button.bg-close {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Inserted that, but seems that is not hidding button after been pressed. I updated first post with html from that button. May you found helpfull.

Comment: It might be due to css not being specific enough.. I updated some info to try.

Comment: Second CSS make the change. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you missed my corrected answer.. Middle CSS worked. Pls change your answer so i can tick as answered.